# Spectacle à entrée(s) payante(s) ?

Tags: pluriel, accord

Je n'arrive pas à me décider si « entrée payante » doit être au pluriel ou au singulier. Le singulier ne me paraît pas correct, mais sans vraiment savoir l'expliquer.

Est-ce qu'il existe une règle pour ça?

Comment: On peut aussi simplement utiliser "spectacle payant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux sont corrects. « Spectacle à entrée payante » fait référence à ce que l'entrée (l'action d'entrer) dans la salle de spectacle est payante. « Spectacle à entrées payantes » fait référence à ce que les entrées (les concrétisations individuelles du droit d'entrer) dans la salle de spectacle sont payantes.

En pratique, [on trouve les deux](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entr%C3%A9e+payante%2Centr%C3%A9es+payantes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3), mais si on examine les occurrences on constate des nuances d'usage. On utilise en général le singulier pour signifier que l'entrée d'un spectacle ou monument donné est payante (« entrée payante sauf les jeudis »). On utilise bien sûr le pluriel lorsqu'on compte le nombre de visiteurs (« un million d'entrées payantes par an »). On a aussi tendance à utiliser le pluriel lorsqu'on considère une catégorie de spectacles et non un spectacle en particulier (« le principe des entrées payantes dans les musées »), même si ce n'est pas complètement tranché.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct.

On the model of *les deux s'écrit*, *un mur de pierre* or *une confiture de fraise*, all depends on what you have in mind:

- *Les deux s'écrit*, if you mean writing the word *deux*.
- *Les deux s'écrivent*, if you mean you can write the two alternatives.
- *un mur de pierre*, if the stone [s.] is a bulding material ;
- *un mur de pierres*, if you talk about the thousand stones [p.] needed to build it.
- *une confiture de fraise*, if you look to the jar with a strawberry [s.] perfume ;
- *une confiture de fraises*, if you look to your wife cooking the strawberries [p.].
- *Un spectacle à entrée payante*, if you consider the way you organize the show ;
- *Un spectacle à entrées payantes*, if you consider each person with a ticket in their hand.

Comment: As much I think this is a good answer, the first case is very rare, almost not constructive, spoiling the rest, in my point of view.

Comment: I feel kind of the same as Jerome. I think the first one should be written as "*« Les deux » s'écrit.*" if you're saying that that particular expression is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Je penche plutôt pour le singulier, l'expression pourrait se dire :

> L'entrée du spectacle est payante.

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, je trouve qu'on voit rarement *entrées payantes* au pluriel sur une annonce de spectacle ou autre.

Cela me parait plus logique au singulier dans le sens ou une entrée est associée à un billet et que chaque personne dispose d'un seul et même billet. En effet, une personne peut payer un billet et venir seule ; dans ce cas, le terme au pluriel serait incorrect.

Je pense donc que *entrée payante* au singulier est plus correct.

Comment: Au moment où on le leur a demandé, Pierre, Paul et Jacques ont présenté leurs entrées payantes au guichetier.

Comment: Pierr, Paul et Jacques ont décidé d'aller au spectacle à entrée payante organisé par l'Association du quatrier.

Comment: @alaind : Je parle spécifiquement de la formule sur une annonce de spectacle ou un flyer. Bien sûr que dans la vie courante, on peut utiliser le pluriel.

Comment: Il avait dans sa poche une entrée payante pour le spectacle. D'ailleurs, il avait laissé sur la table du salon toute une pile d'entrées payantes pour ce spectacle.